# How to move img files only to another folder with orginal folder name+ImageOnly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to move img only files to another folder
if folder didn't exist I will create it with original name+ImageOnly

ex.

```
D:\Test #contain some folder
D:\Test\aaa\img1.jpg
D:\Test\bbb\ccc\img2.jpg
```

```
import os
import shutil

def moveImage(srcdirs):
    for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(srcdirs):
        grand_father = srcdirs #D:\Test
        not_need =('.zip','.js','.html','.log','.lst','.txt','.ini')
        imgExt = ('.jpg','.png','.gif','.jpeg')
        father = os.path.split(roots)[1]+'-ImageOnly'
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(imgExt) and not file.endswith(not_need):
                path = os.path.join(roots,file)
                des= os.path.join(grand_father,father)
                if not os.path.exists(des):
                    createFolder(father)
                    print("folder created")
                shutil.move(path,des)
            elif file.endswith(not_need): #remove unnecessary file
                n1 = os.path.join(roots,file)
                os.remove(n1)


def createFolder(directory):
    dirs = ('./%s/'%directory)
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(dirs):
            os.makedirs(dirs)
    except OSError:
        print ('Error: Creating directory. ' + dirs)


src = r'D:\Test'
moveImage(src)
```

My code gives me
`img1.jpg` move to `aaa-ImageOnly`
but for `img2.jpg` it moved to `ccc-ImageOnly`

I want it to move to `bbb-ImageOnly`
to first subfolder name (I call it right?), not it last subfolder name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import os
import shutil

FOLDER = r'D:\Test'
EXTENSIONS = ('.jpg', '.png', '.gif', '.jpeg')

def move_images(root):
    levels = len(root.split(os.sep))
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(EXTENSIONS):
                src_file = os.path.join(path, file)
                dst_dir = os.path.join(root, '{}-ImageOnly'.format(path.split(os.sep)[levels]))
                dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file)
                if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
                    os.makedirs(dst_dir)
                shutil.move(src_file, dst_file)

move_images(FOLDER)
```

It produces me:

```
D:\Test\aaa-ImageOnly\img1.jpg
D:\Test\bbb-ImageOnly\img2.jpg
```